# php how to remove anything after string if only

Tags: php, html, regex

Actually I want to remove everything from `By`, my answer should be Posted On March 6th. I am using the below code. it is working. but the problem is some times if there is no `By` in the given string then echo value is not showing at all.

```
$s = 'Posted On March 6th By Cristiano';

$variable = substr($s, 0, strpos($s, "By"));
echo $variable;
```

or

```
$variable = strstr($s, 'By', true);
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are <s>two</s> three approaches you could use.

```
$s = 'Posted On March 6th By Cristiano';
$approach1 = explode(' By', $s);
echo $approach1[0];
```

or a regex:

```
echo preg_replace('/ By.*/', '', $s);
```

You could use also `preg_match`.

```
preg_match('/(.*) By/', $s, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

or even `preg_split` (don't see an advantage over the explode in this instance though..).

```
$four = preg_split('/ By/', $s);
echo $four[0];
```

Comment: Regex is overkill for something this simple, even the preg_match manual page recommends using strpos for this situation

Comment: Oh take off the `\n` that was for testing.. although if in double quotes that should be given a newline..

Comment: @rjdown, yea that's why the first answer is a non-regex approach. OP tagged regex so I figured I'd show other approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using strpos inside the substr, just assign it to a separate variable and check its value:

```
<?php
$s = 'Posted On March 6th By Cristiano';
$by_start = strpos($s, "By");
$variable = $by_start === false ? $s : substr($s, 0, $by_start);
echo $variable;
```